# VBA Fax using fax server on server from computer on network

Tags: vba, fax

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2.  I installed the fax server role on the server.  I am able to fax documents using the external fax modem attached to the server from computers attached to the network by printing the documents and selecting "Fax on MYSERVER".  I am able to fax a .pdf using the following code (which I got from mdsn.microsoft.com) from the server but not from any other computer even when logged into the computer using the administrator account.

```
Sub fax_report(location_fax_number, report_name, fax_location, fax_file_path)
    Dim objFaxDocument As New FAXCOMEXLib.FaxDocument
    Dim objFaxServer As New FAXCOMEXLib.FaxServer
    Dim JobID As Object

    On Error GoTo Err_Clear

Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If

    'Connect to the fax server
    objFaxServer.Connect ("\\MYSERVER")

    'Set the fax body
    objFaxDocument.Body = fax_file_path

    'Name the document
    objFaxDocument.DocumentName = report_name

    objFaxDocument.Recipients.add (location_fax_number)

    JobID = objFaxDocument.ConnectedSubmit(objFaxServer)

    objFaxServer.Disconnect

End Sub
```

The error I'm getting is:

- Description: "Operation failed"
- HelpContext: 1000440
- HelpFile: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
  Shared\VBA\VBA7.1\1033\VbLR6.chm"
- LastDllError: 0
- Number: -2147023741
- Source: "FaxComEx.FaxDocument.1"

Although I am able to fax a .pdf from the server when I try from a computer on the network it fails.  I am able to send a .txt file fro a computer on the network.  It looks like the .pdf isn't automatically being converted to a .tiff file like it is when I run the code on the server.  When I run the code from the server Adobe Acrobat Reader DC opens, the .pdf is opened and converted then faxed without error.  Adobe stays open and I can see a temp file was created, it isn't available to be opened from the recent file lists menu.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution.  I needed to set Adobe Acrobat Reader DC as the default program to handle .pdfs on the remote computers.